# Error from Snowflake dll when executing PUT with forward slashes

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I understand the PUT command requires a file path to copy a file to a staging area. For what I'm doing, 
I need to wrap the file path in quotation marks. According to the Snowflake documentation, it is required that the file path use forward slashes (/) instead of the windows-style backslashes () in the file path (for example, if you are trying to PUT the file C:\Documents\file.csv you would have to convert the file path to C:/Documents/file.csv). When I try to execute the PUT command with the forward slashes in the file path, quoted, I get an error from the SnowflakeODBC_sb64_dll. Example: ‘C:/Documents/file.csv’. The error I receive is: “An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal”. If I convert the file path back to backslashes it appears to work fine. Is this a known issue with the Snowflake driver?

I am doing this on Windows, using native Snowflake driver Version 2.20.1

Comment: Actually you can use backslashes.  See these examples -- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-local-file-system-stage.html

Comment: Waldente is correct, you also are missing file:// in front of your file path.

Answer (score 0):

For windows you can use the (//) with PUT Statement.
Check the below Doc:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-local-file-system-stage.html#staging-the-data-files3